# Selecting html dom element inner text using HTML Agility pack

Tags: html, .net, html-agility-pack

Html source has unordered list with country names. It has following html structure

```
<div class="hc_m_content">
    <div class="hc_col">
       <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="/Place/Australia.htm">Australia</a>
         </li>
         <li>
             <a href="/Place/Bahrain.htm">Bahrain</a>
         </li>
         ...
       </ul>
```

using HTML Agility pack I want to select country name.

```
string c = "????";
var nodeList = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(String.Format(c, i));
```

What should I put in c variable having above html structure in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get what you mean by `string c = "????";`, But It can be something like this,

```
var nodeList = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='hc_m_content']//a")
                .Cast<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode>()
                .Select(a => new {
                    Link = a.Attributes["href"].Value,
                    Country = a.InnerText
                })
                .ToList();
```